# Database Relations Normalization to BCNF

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have a theoretical question. I have the relation R(A,B,C,D) and the dependencies B->C, B->D. How I can check whether is in BCNF and if not how do I decompose it to BCNF? The question is from a book. I understand the fundamentals but with this one I didn't succeed, can someone please explain to me?

Comment: What book are you learning BCNF from, how does it say to identify BCNF, what is the algorithm to get to BCNF and where did you get so far with this exercise and where are you stuck? You are effectively asking for a chapter of a textbook. There are many books and slides online. Please get specific.

Answer (score 0):

First compute the closure set of `R`.

- {A} = {A}
- {B} = {B, C, D}
- {C} = {C}
- {D} = {D}
- {A,B} = {A,B,C,D} 
  (which is a key for `R` thus we do not have to compute any closure sets anymore which contain the key `AB`.
- {A,C} = {A, C}
- {A,D} = {A,D}
- {B,C} = {B,C,D}
- {B,D} = {B,C,D}
- {C,D} = {C,D}
- {A,C,D} = {A,B,C,D} (also a key as it contains all attributes of `R` in it's closure).
- {B,C,D} = {B,C,D}

Sets like {A,B,C} were not computed as {A,B} (a key) is a subset. Next we have to determine the new FDs (functional dependencies). I won't explain the process as I'm sure your textbook will describe it. The dependencies are:

- B -> C
- B -> D
- AB -> C
- AB -> D
- BC -> D
- BD -> C
- ACD -> B

Now, every FD that does not have a superkey on it's left side, is a BCNF violation. We can use such violations to split the relation `R`. Our violating FDs are B -> C, B -> D, BC -> D and  BD -> C. We can split the relation on the FD B -> C. The first "half" of the splitted relation will contain all the elements of the closure of the attribute on the left side of the FD, in this case attribute `B`. So our first relation will be `R11(B, C, D)`. Our second relation will contain the left side of the FD (`B`) and the attributes not in the closure of B, which is attribute `A`. So we get relation `R12(A,B)`. Now let's see: relation `R12` is certainly in BCNF as it only contains two attributes. Now let's check relation `R11`. A new key for this relation is `B` as the closure of `B` contains all attributes of `R11`. There are no FDs which are valid on relation `R11` causing violations anymore as they all contain `B` in their left side. So both relations are in BCNF. I hope this was clear enough for you.

Edit: only now noticed this post was 4 months ago... Well I hope it's still of any use (maybe for other members searching for the subject).